why there is a need to send iv with cipher text?
From what I understand by reading TLS 1.2 RFC (key calculation), PRF is used for this with the master key to derive the IV, so both side can generate the same IV because of the nature of PRF.
struct {
       opaque IV[SecurityParameters.record_iv_length];
       block-ciphered struct {
           opaque content[TLSCompressed.length];
           opaque MAC[SecurityParameters.mac_length];
           uint8 padding[GenericBlockCipher.padding_length];
           uint8 padding_length;
       };
   } GenericBlockCipher;

But the above structure defines an IV field, so this structure will be sent when encrypting the TLS packet. Why is there a need for sending IV with every encrypted packet? I'm asking this because the IV is already generated on both side using PRF and will only be used for first block of CBC.

What if someone changes the IV on the path? It is to check that bit-flipping attacks are not applicable.

To cite from the RFC "Currently, the client_write_IV and server_write_IV are only generated
for implicit nonce techniques as described in Section 3.2.1 of
[AEAD].". So no IV's are generated for CBC

TL;DR: Since TLS 1.1, CBC encryption is with random IV explicitly transmitted for each packet, because that's safe. It's made no use of the derived IVs pointed by the question.

I first consider generic CBC encryption of plaintext $P$ consisting of blocks $P_0$, $P_1$… into ciphertext $C$ consisting of as many blocks $C_i=\operatorname{ENC}(K,(P_j\oplus C_{i-1}))$, where $C_{-1}$ is the Initialisation Vector. Decryption uses $P_i=\operatorname{DEC}(K,C_i)\oplus C_{i-1}$.
The requirements for the IV include:

The IV used on the encryption side must somewhat be known on the decryption side. Otherwise decryption fails to restore the first block $P_0$ of the plaintext.
The IV must be different from one encryption to the other (with high probability). Otherwise, if the IV repeats (e.g. is an agreed-upon constant), passive adversaries can detect how many of the first blocks of a new plaintext $P'$ coincide with blocks of earlier plaintext $P$, simply by checking how many of the first $C'_j$ are identical to the $C_j$.
On top of 2, the IV must be unpredictable (ideally: appear random) including with knowledge of the key and plaintext. Arguments:

That's most critical if the same key is reused for encryption or multiple messages. Then, if the IV $C'_{-1}$ for some new plaintext is predictable (e.g. incremented for each new encryption, or chosen by adversaries), adversaries can check a guess $G_i$ of any past plaintext block $P_i$ by submitting a crafted one-block message $P'_0=C'_{-1}\oplus G_i\oplus C_{i-1}$ to an encryption oracle. It follows $P_i=G_i$ if and only if $Q_i=Q'_0$.
It's no good to assume adversaries trying to guess IVs do not know the key. This assumption would let us choose the IV as some agreed-upon function of key and first* block of plaintext: $C_{-1}=f(K,P_0)$. For proper choice of $f$ that could match requirement 2 when $K$ is used for encryption of a single message, block the above attack, and remove the need to transmit the IV. But that's unsatisfactory under so-called multi-target attack.
Assume $n$ ciphertexts for plaintexts with the same known $P_0$ have been encrypted using $n$ keys $K_j$. An adversary can check whether a guess $G$ matches one of the $K_j$, by computing $V=\operatorname{ENC}(G,(P_0\oplus f(G,P_0)))$, and searching $V$ in a static table of $n$ blocks $C_j$ gathered as the first ciphertext block of the $n$ full ciphertexts. If $V$ is not in the table, then $G$ has been quickly ruled out. Otherwise, which is are, an adversary can identify the possible matche(s), make a tentative decryption of the ciphertext(s), and confirm if the guess is right by checking if the corresponding tentative plaintext(s) make sense. This reduces security of the key against brute force search by nearly $\log_2(n)$ bits, as long as the cost of searching the table of $n$ ciphertexts remains low. Perhaps this reduces AES-128 to say 100-bit security, which is a worry.



For these reasons, the simplest and generic method for IV choice in CBC is a random IV block generated and transmitted for each plaintext.

Now back to TLS with CBC encryption.
TLS data is transmitted in individually encrypted packets all using the same key, and it's conceivable that adversaries can inject chosen plaintext. Thus with generic CBC encryption we want an IV for each packet. Thus the one IV initially generated using the PRF won't cut it. TLS 1.2 (and 1.1) just use generic CBC for each packet, thus include an IV in each packet.
This sizable overhead could be safely avoided (e.g. by an auxiliary RNG seeded by material generated at handshake), but this would not be generic CBC. I guess this was not attempted per the once burned, twice shy rationale. As section 6.2.3.2 of the RFC puts it:

(…) in versions of TLS prior to 1.1, there was no IV field, and the last ciphertext block of the  previous record (the "CBC residue") was used as the IV. This was changed to prevent the attacks described in CBCATT.


* implementations of CBC encryption algorithm are online and must start producing the first ciphertext block $C_0$ with knowledge of only the first plaintext block $P_0$, thus the IV can't depend on later blocks.
